# regular expression match, Need to match both number

Tags: php, regex

How to match both number 123,340.00 and 1.9e10?
I have tried regex as below

```
^-?\d+(,)*(\d+\.(\d+e?))
```

But it matches only 123,340.00, I am looking to match both number. any idea? please.

Note: I have tried at online regex tool https://regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

You should allow some digits after `e` at least. Also, `,*` matches zero or more commas, and I think you should only allow comma + digits groups.

I suggest using

```
'~^-?\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?(?:e[+-]?\d+)?$~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS6uI0/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of sting
- `-?` - an optional `-` (you may use `[-+]?` to match plus or minus)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,\d+)*` - zero or more sequences of a comma + 1 or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional decimal part, a dot and 1+ digits
- `(?:e[+-]?\d+)?` - an optional exponent part, `e`, optional minus or plus, and 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Note that the `~i` modifier is used to match both `e` and `E`.

Answer (score 0):

Little less complicated:

```
^-?\d+(,\d+)*(\.\d+(e\d+)?)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something very strict, you can use:

```
^-?[1-9](?:(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?[eE][+-]?[1-9][0-9]*|[0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

It's a bit long but it doesn't match when the number has:

```
012          # leading zeroes
1.20e5       # trailing zeroes in scientific notation
12.3e4       # more that one digit before the dot
1.2e0        # a zero as exponent
1,2345,678,9 # a crazy digit separator
```